# Moving character with vectors

Tags: vector, xna, angle

Whenever I have a character and I want him to move to an object I always have to convert it to an angle, ex:

```
int adjacent = myPosition.X - thatPosition.X;
int opposite = myPosition.Y - thatPosition.Y;

double angle = Math.atan2(adjacent, opposite);

myPosition.X += Math.cos(angle);
myPosition.Y += Math.sin(angle);
```

Is there an easier way to move an object to another by just using vectors and not converting to an angle and back, if so I would appreciate if you showed how and/or pointed me to a site that could show me.

p.s. I am coding in XNA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can minimize the trig & take a more linear algebra approach. That would look something like this:

```
//class scope fields
Vector2 myPosition, velocity, myDestination;
float speed;

//in the initialize method
myPosition = new Vector2(?, ?);
myDestination = new Vector2(?, ?);
speed = ?f;//usually refers to "units (or pixels) per second"

//in the update method to change the direction traveled by changing the destination
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
myDestination = new Vector2(?', ?');//change direction by changing destination
Velocity = Vector2.Normalize(myDestination - myPosition);
velocity *= speed;

myPosition += velocity * elapsed;

//or instead of changing destination to change velocity direction, you can simply rotate the velocity vector
velocity = Vector2.Transform(velocity, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(someAngle);
velocity.Normalize();
velocity *= speed;

myPosition += velocity * elapsed;
```

The only angles/trig used here is the trig that is embedded in the CreateRotationZ() method and it is happening behind the scenes by the xna framework.